# How to get the pairs from one list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new in Prolog and I can't figure out how to obtain the result.

I want to compute the possible combinations of pairs in the list.

Example: input is a list [a,b,c], I want to obtain the pairs (a,b),(a,c),(b,c). I want each pair to be saved as a list.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part of this assignment is confusing to you? What have you tried writing? It's hard to give generic help on a problem this small that won't amount to giving you the complete answer. I imagine since you're a student you aren't wanting to commit academic fraud by cheating.

Comment: This is what I have done so far: pairs(L,R) :-
    findall((A,B),(member(A,L),member(B,L),A \== B),R).
But I don't get 3 pairs, I get 6.. This is the output: L = [ (a, b), (a, c), (b, a), (b, c), (c, a), (c, b)]. I need only (a,b),(a,c),(b,c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, you should try to find the solution by yourself.

You can obtain the result with just a single findall/3, using append/3 to get *together* the first element of the pair and the rest of elements, and a single member/2 suffices to select the second element of the pair.

Of course, the actual solution is far less verbose and more clearer. You'll learn much if you try to assemble it...

```
all_pairs(L, R) :-
    findall((A,B), (..., ...), R).
```

yields

```
?- all_pairs([a,b,c],L).
L = [ (a, b), (a, c), (b, c)].
```

*edit* You just need to fix the details:

```
...((A,B), (append(_, [A|T], L), ...), R).
```

to generate contextually both the first element, and you know how to get B .

Note that [A,B] it's different than (A,B), that you required in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. This is what I have done using append: 'pairs(L,R) :-
    findall([A,B],(append(A,X,L),A \== [],member(B,X)),R).
' This is the output: 'L = [[[a], b], [[a], c], [[a, b], c]].' There is still an error in the third pair, how do I correct that? Your help is greatly appreciated.